# what is browser compatibility of node package 'events'?

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

I use `"events": "^1.0.2"`
I can't find documentation about the browser compatibility.
anyone knows about this?

---

my reasons asking this is actually I am using `events` with flux and react like below.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var AuthStore = objectAssign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  addSuccessListener: function(cb) {
    this.on(SUCCESS_EVENT, cb);
  },
  removeSuccessListener: function(cb) {
    this.removeListener(SUCCESS_EVENT, cb);
  }
});
```

I am wondering if IE 8 below versions would work with `on()` and `removeListener()`.

Comment: Browser compatibility? That's a Node.js package, nothing to do with browsers.

Comment: @Michelem I updated my question

Comment: It says ["for all engines"](https://github.com/Gozala/events) so I assume that it has been tested in browsers as well. The code also doesn't seem to depend on anything besides plain JS (so it's not tied to Node.js only).

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/Gozala/events

> You usually do not have to install events yourself! If your code runs in Node.js, events is built in. If your code runs in the browser, **bundlers like browserify or webpack also include the events module**.

At first I was confused that the events module was working on browser when I compiled it with webpack, so I am highlighting this here for future reference.